# How to set panel, buttons, labels and menu strip to be transparent?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to keep transparency of buttons and labels which are inside of a panel control.
I set the `BackColor` properties to `Transparent`, but it doesn't work.

Also I tried

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
Me.Panel1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

The screenshot below is our design plan. We try to set an image below the panel, buttons and Menu Strip. Can you tell me please if this is possible, and if so, how to?

http://www.gomidjets.com/images/upper.png

Answer (score 0):

With regards to custom designing your Form in WinForms, it isn't supported very well. Only some of the controls support transparency, and it really impacts on performance. If you are avid that it must be transparent, make sure that your Form has its `TransparencyKey` set to a value, and then change each of the `Panels, Buttons, Labels` and `MenuStrips` background to this color (Usually some obtuse color).

If your program is in its early stages, I strongly suggest that you give WPF some serious consideration. From the level of customization to your Form you are doing, you would be much better doing WPF. I myself have just moved over, and this is a screeny of my first project in WPF (And I've learnt this all from StackOverflow, so you should pick it up pretty fast!)

[image]

As you can see, literally everything on that form has been customised, and **every single** control supports full `Transparency`!

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying winforms since it's not on early stage. I tried your advice and I now understand that 'transparent' means to see the form/desktop behind my form. Actually when I was saying 'Transparent' I meant to see the image button (picture) that is placed on the same form. I'm just trying to set a label with text, while the background comes from a picture behind. Is that possible? I couldn't find it. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1918255 could you please upload a picture of what your form currently looks like? As far as I know, `Labels` already support transparency how you want it, as well as `Panels` (If you set border to None). Therefore, it is only the `Buttons` and `MenuStrip` that require transparency.

Comment: Please have a look: http://www.gomidjets.com/images/design-n-runtime.jpg

At the top you'll see the design time (crimson color was defined as the transparentkey color)
At the bottom you'll see the run-time

I wish I could put the picture in background while the buttons and labels inside the panel are shown above in transparent

Comment: As far as I can see, what you are trying to do, is very difficult to do in WinForms. I recommend trying to replace all your buttons with `Labels` and set your own images for them and manipulate the `MouseHover`, `MouseEnter` etc events to make them appear as buttons. As for the file menu, I would yet again suggest making your own custom `MenuStrip`. Possibly using `Labels` yet again. However, this whole process might take a little while.

Comment: If you could possibly tell me exactly what does and doesn't work with regard to your current Form? The image you just showed me, shows a glitchy background image, and I am not too sure about the `MenuStrip`.

Comment: If you have not progressed far down the UI development path, I **strongly** suggest that either you consider a less modified approach or move to WPF. WPF is almost exactly the same in terms of VB code, the only difference is the vastly more customizable UI.

Comment: Thank you. However I could use the following code and now it's start being transparent: http://gomidjets.com/images/transparent2.jpg

menuStrip1.Parent = PictureBox1
menuStrip1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
panel1.Parent = PictureBox1
panel1.BackColor = Color.Transparent

Yet I have two problems: a) the quality of the image which is part of picturebox1 is very low (see screenshot), while the same image on the menustrip part has better quality (b) Since menustrip is linked to picturebox, it gets its location properties. I'd prefer to align the menustrip to the left side

Any advice?
Thank you